# "Error: A React component suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified." [React Lazy & Suspense]

Tags: reactjs

I have a React App which works well, but I want to implement Code Splitting by using Lazy & Suspense from React,

I tried to do it for routes but I get the following error

```
Error: A React component suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified.

Add a <Suspense fallback=...> component higher in the tree to provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display.
```

Here's my code :

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";
const Home = lazy(() => import("./pages/Home"));
const Stream = lazy(() => import("./pages/Stream"));
const Contact = lazy(() => import("./pages/Contact"));
const Faq = lazy(() => import("./pages/Faq"));
const About = lazy(() => import("./pages/About"));
const Twitch = lazy(() => import("./pages/Twitch"));
const Chat = lazy(() => import("./pages/Chat"));
const Error = lazy(() => import("./pages/Error"));
const Backdrop = lazy(() => import("./components/Backdrop"));

function Router() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Backdrop />}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/stream" exact component={Stream} />
        <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/faq" exact component={Faq} />
        <Route path="/a-propos" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/twitch" exact component={Twitch} />
        <Route path="/chat" exact component={Chat} />
        <Route component={Error} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export default Router;
```

I don't know what's the issue with this ?

**Edit: Backdrop component is a component from Material UI [enter link description here](https://material-ui.com/components/backdrop/)**

Comment: You should not lazy load your `Backdrop` which is fallback component.